# The quotient of $\pi_n(X,A,x_0)$ by the action of $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ is Abelian

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading Spanier's algebraic topology book and he states that the quotient of $\pi_n(X,A,x_0)$ by the action of $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ is Abelian. I think there is a typo here somewhere as for proof he references a lemma 7.3.12 which deals explicitly with $\pi_2$, not $\pi_n$ for arbitrary $n$, using a proof that really does not seem to generalize well at all (although perhaps there's some inductive bootstrapping using an isomorphism $\pi_n(X,A)\cong \pi_{n-1}(\Sigma X, \Sigma A)$ or something of this ilk that I'm missing.)

Is the statement true? Is there a proof of it?

Comment: $\pi_n(X,A)$ is abelian for $n>2$, and therefore so is any quotient of it. 7.3.12 covers the $n=2$ case.

Comment: Thanks. I was being an idiot. For some reason I thought the standard proof that the higher homotopy groups are Abelian would not generalize correctly to the relative case.